# What is mailto´s URL on a webpage

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, mailto

if you have a email address on the webpage - mailto:

then - is it possible to activate the mailto directly via URL - for example

http://www.homepage.com/mailto:email@email.com   URL and if putting the url directly into the browser

then the mailto opens just as it would open if clicked to the email address on the home page

Comment: Elements on a web page do not necessarily have their own URLs.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the "http://www.homepage.com/" and just use "mailto:email@email.com".

Comment: +1. Why even bother with a URL when a simple `mailto` would suffice? The question must be missing some key info, worded improperly, or something.

Answer (score 2):

This would not work, because the web browser would just send a request to www.hompage.com for a page called mailto:email@email.com.  In any situation where you would want to do this, you would be able to do a regular mailto: style link, such as:

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com">MAIL ME</a>
```